# IntentService within Service

Tags: android, service, inner-classes, intentservice

I have an IntentService started within Service. The problem is, when the Service fires intent to start IntentService, nothing happens (the intent doesnt reach the IntentService).

Details:
The Service is class on its own, the IntentService is defined as an inner class within Service. The reason is to share global variables (without passing them).

My geuss on where the problem might be:
All services are defined in Manifest this way: (within application tag)

```
<service android:name=".MyService" />
<service android:name=".ConnectionIntentService" />
<service android:name=".ListeningIntentService" />
```

- isnt there some problem with IntentService being inner class of Service?

Otherwise, the IntentService is started like this:

```
Intent Start_ConnectionIS = new Intent(this, ConnectionIntentService.class);
startService(Start_ConnectionIS);
```

- the startService(Start_ConnectionIS) is called within BroadcastReceiver registered within Service (so far I have not experienced any problems with this)

Comment: Did you override `protected abstract void onHandleIntent (Intent intent)` in the intentService? can you provide your full code of first Service?

Comment: thank you for your interest, the problem is solved (CommonsWare answered all my doubts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Service is class on its own, the IntentService is defined as an inner class within Service

That's not going to work, unless perhaps the `IntentService` is a static inner class.

> The reason is to share global variables (without passing them).

There are no global variables in Java. The closest analogue are static data members, and you do not need to use an inner class to "share" those.

> isnt there some problem with IntentService being inner class of Service?

Your manifest claims that all of your services are standalone public classes, not inner classes.

If you elect to have a `BarIntentService` that is a static inner class of `FooService`, the syntax would be `android:name=".FooService$BarIntentService"`. A non-static inner class cannot be used for a `Service`, as Android cannot create an instance of it.

Comment: To be honest, this is the most straight forward, most comprehensive response I have ever obtained on stackoverflow.